# Understanding the issue with my custom class for Item and inventory system for game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry, but i can not ask a question without some introducing. (If you are not sure whether to read it all, I still try to ask a question, problem is if i try to change my item properties, it applies to all other the same items, how to fix this?)

I Have Class `Item` with some properties and variables, like `itemCost`, `durability` etc.

Class `Weapon` inherits `Item`.

I Have `ItemGenerator` class, that initialize all items in one array. It contains functuons like:

```
private static Weapon CreateUniqueWeaponForItemList(int ID, int itemLevel, 
..... string description) {
   Weapon item = new Weapon();

   item.ID = ID;
   item.ItemLevel = itemLevel;
   ...
   ...
   item.Description = description
   return item;
}
```

something like that.
This item list initialize at start of the game. 
I Have Item array that contain all items.

```
public static Item[] ItemList = new Item[200];
```

Below are list of all unique items in game, created by function above, :

```
ItemList[1] = CreateUniqueWeaponForItemList(1, 5, ....., "this is item!");
ItemList[2] = ....
```

and like that.
This works great for now. When i generate item i just use Item ID, for specify what item i want to create. Also it easy to save and load, just store item's `ID` in `PlayerPrefs`.

But when i start to add additional functional (like item upgrades, damage upgrade and something) i realized that this architecture is bad.

If player have two or more same items, here the problems begin. If i try to change `Item` properties, they applied to `ItemList[ID]`, not to item i want to.

I think im need to paste code here to be clear. I have inventory system, with 
`private List<Item> _inventory = new List<Item>();` in `Player` class. I have treasure chest which get item from `ItemList` to create some

```
loot.Add(ItemGenerator.CreateUniqueItem(2));
```

`loot` is `Item` variable in `Chest` class. Below are explanations of `CreateUniqueItem`

```
   public static Item CreateUniqueItem(int ID) {
      if (ID > ItemList.Length) {
         return null;
      }

      if (ItemList[ID] != null) {
         return ItemList[ID];
      }
      else {
         return ItemList[0];
      }
   }
```

When item created, player can grab it to inventory. I Just `_inventory.add(item);`, for example `item` is `ItemList[2]`

```
    Player.Insntance.Inventory.Add(chest.loot[2]);
    chest.loot.RemoveAt(2);
```

chest.loot is

```
public List<Item> loot = new List<Item>();
```

that contain all items to grab.

I think problem is here.

### -----------------------------------------

So here is question itself.
If i want to do upgrade item i use

`_inventory[0].MaxDamage++`

but MaxDamage increases on all other same items in Player's inventory, i can't understand, why? I do not use `ItemList[ID].MaxDamage++`

I think i should save all created unique items in some file or something like this, and do reference to them from inventory, rather than give a link to inventory.

Or store in file only item ID, and add to items `int` variable like `upgradeLevel` and store this. So depends of `upgradeLevel` items can get buffs to damage.

But is it right? And what best way to do this?

### -----------------------------------------

Here is short paste of Item class:

```
public class Item  {
private int _ID
private int _itemLevel;
...
...

    public Item(){
       _ID = 0;
       _itemLevel = 0;
       ...
       ...
    }

    public ID{
       get { return _ID; }
       set { _ID = value; }

    public int ItemLevel {
       get { return _itemLevel; }
       set { _itemLevel = value; }
    }
...
...
...
}
```

Weapon class is same, but have additional variables, like damage.

```
public class Weapon : Item
{
    private int _maxDamage;

    public Weapon() {
        _maxDamage = 0;
    }

    public int MaxDamage {
       get { return _maxDamage; }
       set { _maxDamage = value; }
    }
}
```

I can give full listing of code on GitHub if necessary. But i think, code i was pasted above more than enought. I hope I do not forget anything.

I would not be surprised if the problem is trivial, but for some reason I can not understand it and it causes headache.

I'm sorry if there is too much text, but I could not shorter.

Also sorry for my bad english spelling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're storing references in your array, and so there is only ever a single item in existence.    Solving this can be done a number of ways.  Essentially, your "item list" is almost like a list of templates.  A bit like Plato's theory of perfect form.  Whenever you bring an item in to existence in the game (be it in the chest, or the player's inventory) you want to clone the item.

Think of your sword item array as the "concept of a sword", and whenever there is one in a chest, we "clone" that template.  The chest now contains a duplicate of the template.  Obviously when the player takes the sword, we merely transfer from one container to another (we don't leave the sword in the chest, it's transferred to the player's inventory).

So, how can we do this?  Well, we can use cloning.  Your item base class can therefore look like this:

```
// Not tying ourselves just to weapons here...  what about food, clothes, etc..?
public abstract class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Let's have a copy constructor
    public Item(Item other)
    {
        ID = other.ID;
        Name = other.Name;
    }

    // This part is important!
    public abstract Item Clone();
}
```

Good. We have an item.  And it has some basic properties.  Let's make a weapon.

```
public class Weapon : Item
{
    public int Damage { get; set; }

    // also has a copy constructor
    public Weapon(Weapon other) : base(other) // Item copies it's stuff!
    {
        Damage = other.Damage;
    }

    // Need to implement this:
    public override Item Clone() { return new Weapon(this); }
}
```

You can now derive a whole bunch of other stuff (food, clothes, dirty magazines, works on Plato, etc).

Now, you can have an array of these `Item` instances, and whenever you want to place one in a chest in the game, you merely go:

```
Item newItem = itemList[index].Clone();
```

This effectively creates a new instance of *whatever the item was*.  Food will get cloned properly.  So, if the player has a cloned sword, it's now ok to clone it, and increase the damage of it - because it is a *different* sword (but based on Plato's original sword!).

This isn't the only way to solve this, and inheritance trees can get pretty messy when items have multiple different kinds of properties and there are potentially hundreds of slight variations.  I favour component-based design in those instances, but that's a bit beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for fast and descriptive answer! Now it works great! Sorry that my reputation does not allow me to rate you up. Once again many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find this problem gets simpler if you derive items from **ScriptableObject**.

ScriptableObject (like GameObject) has to be instantiated explicitly so you can be clear when you are dealing with an instance and when you're dealing with a ScriptableObject asset.  The other nice thing is that you can then create your template assets ('the +1 sword', 'the cloak of invisiblity', etc) and edit them by hand (setting individual item properties, etc) and inspect them. Plus all the boring stuff like managing instance ids and manual serialization is done for you.

Comment: Thanks for this information about ScriptableObject, I didn't know about that until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using just one item class. Switch item type by using enums, in my opinion it´s way more flexible.
I´m using something like the following code, because using inheritance is a messy thing... sooo^^

ehm... this example is for unity users ;)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    void Start()
    {
        Test();

        AddItem( new ItemGenerator().GetRandomItem());
        AddItem( new ItemGenerator(ItemType.Weapon, "New Cool Weapon Item", UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,100),  UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,100)));
        Item item = new Item();
        item.ItemType = ItemType.Quest;
        AddItem(item);
        AddItem(new Item());
        AddItem( new ItemGenerator().GetRandomItem("Random Test Item 1 2 3"));

        AddItem( item.Clone());
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }

    void Test()
    {
        Debug.Log("Test starts");
        // example flexibility
        Item item = new Item();

        item.ItemType = Itemtype.Weapon;
        if(item.ItemType == Itemtype.Weapon)
           Debug.Log(item.WeaponProperties.GetDps(item));



        item.ItemType = Itemtype.Armor;
        if(item.ItemType == Itemtype.Armor)
           Debug.Log(item.ArmorProperties.Defense);


        switch(item.ItemType)
        {
            case ItemType.Weapon: Debug.Log("Do Weapon Stuff - instantiate at weapon spawnpoint"); break;
            case ItemType.Armor: Debug.Log("Do Armor Stuff - instantiate at spawnpoint"); break;
            default: Debug.Log("what ever..."); break;
        }

        // example item generator
        Item item2 = new ItemGenerator(ItemType.Weapon);
        Debug.Log(item2.Name);

        Item item3 = new ItemGenerator(ItemType.Armor, "New Armor Item");
        Debug.Log(item3.Name);

        item3.ItemType = ItemType.Weapon;
        item3.Name = "Ultra Sword";
        Debug.Log(item3.Name);

        Item item4 = new ItemGenerator(ItemType.Weapon, "New Weapon Item", UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,100),  UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,100));
        Debug.Log(item3.Name);

        Item item5 = new ItemGenerator().GetRandomItem();
        Debug.Log(item2.Name);
        Debug.Log(item2.ItemType);

        // clone item

        Item item6 = item5.Clone();
        Debug.Log(item2.Name);

        Debug.Log("Test ends");
    }
}


public enum ItemType
{
    Weapon, Armor, Consumable, Quest, Key //...
}

public class Item // :ScriptableObject
{
    public string Name = "FooItem";
    public ItemType Itemtype;
    public Attributes Attributes = new Attributes();
    public WeaponProperties WeaponProperties = new WeaponProperties();
    public ArmorProperties ArmorProperties = new ArmorProperties();
    public Item Clone()
    {
        return (Item)MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class WeaponProperties
{
    public int MinimalDamage = 10;
    public int MaximalDamage= 20;
    public float Speed = 1.5f;
    public static float GetDps(Item weapon)
    {
        return Mathf.RoundToInt(((weapon.WeaponProperties.MinimalDamage + weapon.WeaponProperties.MaximalDamage) * 0.5f) / weapon.WeaponProperties.Speed);
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class ArmorProperties
{
    public int Defense = 25;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Attributes
{
    public int Strength = 25;
    public int Stamina = 20;
}

public class ItemGenerator : Item
{
    public ItemGenerator(ItemType itemType) : this(itemType, "NewNamelessItem")
    {
    }
    public ItemGenerator(ItemType itemType, string name)this(itemType, name, 0,  0)
    {
    }
    public ItemGenerator(ItemType itemType, string name, int strength, int stamina) : this(itemType, name, strength, stamina,  0)
    {
    }
    public ItemGenerator(ItemType itemType, string name, int strength, int stamina, int defense)
    {
        Name = name;
        Attributes.Strength = strength;
        Attributes.Stamina = stamina;
        switch(item.ItemType)
        {
            case ItemType.Weapon: 
                break;
            case ItemType.Armor: 
                ArmorProperties.Defense = defense;
                break;
            default: Debug.Log("what ever..."); break;
        }
    }

    public Item GetRandomItem()
    {
        return GetRandomItem( "New Random Item");
    }

    public Item GetRandomItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Attributes.Strength = Random.Range(0,100);
        Attributes.Stamina = Random.Range(0,100);
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemType));
        ItemType = (ItemType)values.GetValue(Random.Range(0, values.Length));
        switch(item.ItemType)
        {
            case ItemType.Weapon: 
                break;
            case ItemType.Armor: 
                ArmorProperties.Defense = Random.Range(0,100);
                break;
            default: Debug.Log("what ever..."); break;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Finally this means every item can be change to a totally different item and you have full control about all the variables.